# Synergy keyboard "lock": Mac OS Server + Opera web browser(?) + Google Apps

Tags: macos, opera, synergy

### Environment

**Synergy configuration:**

- Server: Mac OS X (Mavericks, 10.9.2), running Synergy 1.4.17 (premium).

  Client: Windows 8, running Synergy 1.4.17 (premium).

Software/apps running when problem occurs:

- Opera web browser (running on server)

  <strike>Google email/calendar/other Google Apps in one or more tabs of Opera</strike>

### Problem

The problem I see is that at "random" intervals, my Synergy client will lose keyboard input. All keyboard input is directed to the server instead, although mouse input functions normally on the client computer. The only way I have found to break the lock and restore keyboard input to the client computer is to quit Opera, or sometimes to close one or more Google Apps tabs, at which point Synergy performs as expected.

I have not observed this problem with other web browsers, although I don't use them much. I'll try that and post observations. I have just now enabled logging on Synergy to see if that gives any errors or useful info.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, with the same or similar parameters? Anyone have any suggested troubleshooting steps?

**Edit 2014.05.13:** testing indicates that Google Apps is not actually a factor in this problem, just a coincidental element